# error reading configuration while deploying to aks

Tags: azure, deployment, kubernetes, azure-devops, aks

I am using Azure devops for regulation CI/CD in my project , i have a kubernetes cluster running through aks(azure kubernetes service) , i have used azure repo and everything and , every required file(viz. azure-pipeline file and services and deployment) is auto generated and i haven't altered anything in it , it builds nicely , but it fails in the deployment phase , I encounter this error as shown below ,

Error:

```
/usr/bin/kubectl apply -f /home/vsts/work/_temp/bookstore_1570774284000,/home/vsts/work/_temp/bookstore_1570774284001 --namespace default
error when retrieving current configuration of:
Resource: "apps/v1beta1, Resource=deployments", GroupVersionKind: "apps/v1beta1, Kind=Deployment"
Name: "alesblaze/bookstore", Namespace: "default"
Object: &{map["apiVersion":"apps/v1beta1" "kind":"Deployment" "metadata":map["annotations":map["kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":""] "name":"alesblaze/bookstore" "namespace":"default"] "spec":map["replicas":'\x01' "template":map["metadata":map["labels":map["app":"alesblaze/bookstore"]] "spec":map["containers":[map["image":"***/alesblaze/bookstore" "name":"alesblaze/bookstore" "ports":[map["containerPort":'\u1f90']]]] "imagePullSecrets":[map["name":"bookstoreappacrd0a8-auth"]]]]]]}
from server for: "/home/vsts/work/_temp/bookstore_1570774284000": invalid resource name "alesblaze/bookstore": [may not contain '/']
error when retrieving current configuration of:
Resource: "/v1, Resource=services", GroupVersionKind: "/v1, Kind=Service"
Name: "alesblaze/bookstore", Namespace: "default"
Object: &{map["apiVersion":"v1" "kind":"Service" "metadata":map["annotations":map["kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":""] "name":"alesblaze/bookstore" "namespace":"default"] "spec":map["ports":[map["port":'\u1f90']] "selector":map["app":"alesblaze/bookstore"] "type":"LoadBalancer"]]}
from server for: "/home/vsts/work/_temp/bookstore_1570774284001": invalid resource name "alesblaze/bookstore": [may not contain '/']
##[error]error when retrieving current configuration of:
Resource: "apps/v1beta1, Resource=deployments", GroupVersionKind: "apps/v1beta1, Kind=Deployment"
Name: "alesblaze/bookstore", Namespace: "default"
Object: &{map["apiVersion":"apps/v1beta1" "kind":"Deployment" "metadata":map["annotations":map["kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":""] "name":"alesblaze/bookstore" "namespace":"default"] "spec":map["replicas":'\x01' "template":map["metadata":map["labels":map["app":"alesblaze/bookstore"]] "spec":map["containers":[map["image":"***/alesblaze/bookstore" "name":"alesblaze/bookstore" "ports":[map["containerPort":'\u1f90']]]] "imagePullSecrets":[map["name":"bookstoreappacrd0a8-auth"]]]]]]}
from server for: "/home/vsts/work/_temp/bookstore_1570774284000": invalid resource name "alesblaze/bookstore": [may not contain '/']
error when retrieving current configuration of:
Resource: "/v1, Resource=services", GroupVersionKind: "/v1, Kind=Service"
Name: "alesblaze/bookstore", Namespace: "default"
Object: &{map["apiVersion":"v1" "kind":"Service" "metadata":map["annotations":map["kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":""] "name":"alesblaze/bookstore" "namespace":"default"] "spec":map["ports":[map["port":'\u1f90']] "selector":map["app":"alesblaze/bookstore"] "type":"LoadBalancer"]]}
from server for: "/home/vsts/work/_temp/bookstore_1570774284001": invalid resource name "alesblaze/bookstore": [may not contain '/']
Finishing: Deploy to Kubernetes cluster
```

Edit :

**Service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: alesblaze/bookstore
spec:
    type: LoadBalancer
    ports:
    - port: 8080 
    selector:
        app: alesblaze/bookstore
```

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion : apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: alesblaze/bookstore 
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: alesblaze/bookstore 
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: alesblaze/bookstore 
          image: bookstoreappacr.azurecr.io/alesblaze/bookstore 
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
```

**Kubernetes version : 1.13.10**

Comment: Please provide your YAMLs and Kubernetes version.

Comment: there you go! @PjoterS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You received this issue because your YAMLs have some syntax issues, mostly too much spaces (also if you will use **TAB** instead of spaces it will also generate YAML syntax issue). For example, instead of

```
metadata:
    name: alesblaze/bookstore
```

should be

```
metadata:
  name: alesblaze/bookstore
```

Sub-parameter should be on level of the third letter. You can base your YAMLs on [Kubernetes doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment).
I will paste proper YAMLs below. 
**Before that you have to know why you cannot use "/" in some of your parameters.**

Even if in YAML syntax is correct (you can validate your yamls [here](http://www.yamllint.com)), there are other validations.

```
apiVersion : apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: alesblaze/bookstore
```

If you will create deployment with `--dry-run` flag which skip some validations, `kubectl` will crate this deployment.

> `--dry-run`=false: If true, only print the object that would be sent, without sending it.

```
$ kubectl create deployment alesblaze/bookstore --image=nginx --dry-run
deployment.apps/alesblaze/bookstore created (dry run)
```

However, if you will want to use it without this flag with all validation you will receive error:

```
$ kubectl create deployment alesblaze/bookstore --image=nginx
The Deployment "alesblaze/bookstore" is invalid: 
* metadata.name: Invalid value: "alesblaze/bookstore": a DNS-1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'example.com', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*')
* metadata.labels: Invalid value: "alesblaze/bookstore": a valid label must be an empty string or consist of alphanumeric characters, '-', '_' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'MyValue',  or 'my_value',  or '12345', regex used for validation is '(([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9_.]*)?[A-Za-z0-9])?')
* spec.selector.matchLabels: Invalid value: "alesblaze/bookstore": a valid label must be an empty string or consist of alphanumeric characters, '-', '_' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'MyValue',  or 'my_value',  or '12345', regex used for validation is '(([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9_.]*)?[A-Za-z0-9])?')
* spec.selector: Invalid value: v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{"app":"alesblaze/bookstore"}, MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: invalid label selector
```

Means that deployment name, label, selectors in Kubernetes cannot contain **"/"** because it will not pass all validations. Your have received similar issue:

```
Object: &{map["apiVersion":"apps/v1beta1" "kind":"Deployment" "metadata":map["annotations":map["kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":""] "name":"alesblaze/bookstore" "namespace":"default"] "spec":map["replicas":'\x01' "template":map["metadata":map["labels":map["app":"alesblaze/bookstore"]] "spec":map["containers":[map["image":"***/alesblaze/bookstore" "name":"alesblaze/bookstore" "ports":[map["containerPort":'\u1f90']]]] "imagePullSecrets":[map["name":"bookstoreappacrd0a8-auth"]]]]]]}
from server for: "/home/vsts/work/_temp/bookstore_1570774284000": invalid resource name "alesblaze/bookstore": [may not contain '/']
```

It is describe in [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/names/#names) about names.

> By convention, the names of Kubernetes resources should be up to
>   maximum length of 253 characters and consist of lower case
>   alphanumeric characters, -, and ., but certain resources have more
>   specific restrictions.

Others resources like `image` or `apiVersion` allow to use **"/"**.

Below YAMLS which will allow you to create Deployment and Service (with proper spaces and allowed characters):

**Deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion : apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: alesblaze-bookstore
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: alesblaze-bookstore
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: alesblaze-bookstore 
        image: bookstoreappacr.azurecr.io/alesblaze/bookstore 
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

**Service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: alesblaze-bookstore
spec:
  selector:
    app: alesblaze-bookstore
  ports:
  - port: 8080 
  type: LoadBalancer
```

If it helped, please upvote/accept my answer.